# Dropping a global temp table does not drop its index

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, temp-tables

Problem summary:

I created a global temp table and then I created a clustered index (added a primary key clustered constraint) on the table. I dropped the table assuming that it will also drop the index. I then recreated the table with the same name without problems. Then, when I tried to recreate the same index with the same name I get the error:

```
The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'dbo.##MyTempTable' and the index name 'PK_TempSampleID'.
```

Problem details:

I need to create a global temp table and load records into this table in a particular order using:

```
SELECT FROM SomeTable INTO ##MyTempTable WHERE SomeCondition
```

ORDER BY does not do the job here, so I created a clustered index (primary key clustered constraint). This did the trick and my records were ordered by the respective field.

However, I encountered a different problem: I dropped the table and recreated it without problems but when I tried recreating the index I got the above mentioned error.

I tried dropping the index using:

```
DROP INDEX PK_TempSampleID ON ##MyTempTable
```

And I got this error message:

```
Cannot drop the index '##TempFormattedSnapshot.PK_TempSampleID', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
```

I researched posts on this and other forums and all seem to advise that when dropping a temp table the index on that table is also dropped. My experience shows me otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message

> The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key
>   was found for the object name 'dbo.##MyTempTable' and the index name
>   'PK_TempSampleID'.

means that there are duplicate values in the column(s) for which you are trying to create a unique index. In other words, not all values are unique.

It has nothing to do with the previously existed index of the same name.

When you drop a table, all indexes on that table are dropped as well.

---

You have another problem, which is out of the scope of this question. You said "load records into this table in a particular order". You'd better ask another question explaining what you are trying to achieve, because there is no such thing as "inserting rows into a table in a particular order". The only thing that you can do is generate `IDENTITY` values in a particular order when inserting rows.

Anyway, this is not the point of this question.

Comment: Indeed! I found duplicate keys. While the original key in the source table is an identity, on subsequent runs with different filtering conditions the query picked up duplicates through an unexpected cartesian product! Tanks for pointing this out. I should've read the error message properly.